# Nested Form Unknown Attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a small expense tracking app. Using the nested_form gem to add line items. There is an Expense model which accepts nested attributes. Items belong to expenses.

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :organization
    belongs_to :department
    has_many :expense_types
    has_many :items

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

The items model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :expense
end
```

The controller create action action looks like:

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @expense = Expense.new
    end
    def create
            @expense = Expense.new(expense_params)
            if @expense.save
                flash[:notice] = "Expense Report Submitted"
                redirect_to @expense
            else
                render 'new'
            end
        end

        private
        def expense_params
            params.require(:expense).permit(:department_id, :expense_type_id, :notes, items_attributes: [:id, :description, :amount, :issue_date, :_destroy])
        end
    end
```

The new expense form looks like:

```
<%= nested_form_for (@expense) do |f| %>    
    <% if @expense.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@expense.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
          this expense from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% @expense.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class"row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :department_id %><br>
                <%= f.collection_select(:department_id, Department.all, :id, :department_name, prompt: true, class: "dropdown-menu") %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :expense_type_id %><br>
                <%= f.collection_select(:expense_type_id, ExpenseType.all, :id, :expense_name, prompt: true, class: "form-control")  %>
            </div>
            <%= f.fields_for :items do |i| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= i.label :description%>
                    <%= i.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= i.label :amount%>
                    <%= i.text_field :amount, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= i.label :issue_date%>
                    <%= i.date_select :issue_date, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
                <%= i.link_to_remove "Remove", class: "btn btn-default" %>
            <% end %>
            <div><p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Expense", :items, class: "btn btn-default" %></p></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :notes %>
              <%= f.text_area :notes, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
            <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was able to save expenses before adding the nested attributes. After doing that, whenever I hit the submit button, I get the ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ExpensesController#create error. It's weird to see unknown attribute: expense_id. Did I miss something here?

Comment: Can you post your `form` code?

Comment: @Pavan I've updated the question with the form code.

Comment: Can you post your `new` method and also the `full form code` please?

Comment: @Pavan I have updated the question with the controller and full form code.

Comment: You've to add expense_id as attr_accessible in items model. That could be the reason

Comment: @sk Can you be a bit more elaborate? I don't see any such step in the official doc. Since this is a Rails 4 app, the strong parameters in the controller ensure which attributes to allow.

Comment: Look at my answer - it's the fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nested Form**

To the best of my knowledge, the `nested_form` gem basically just creates a [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) instance for your form. If this is the case (it more or less *has* to be), then you've got several issues you need to consider

By the way, looking at the `nested_form` documentation, it seems it was primarily designed for **Rails 3**. When it mentioned about `attr_accessible`, it now means to focus on `strong_params` (if you're using Rails 4 of course)

--

**Build**

As mentioned by `Mandeep`, you need to ensure you're *building* the correct ActiveRecord objects for your form. `form_for` works by taking an ActiveRecord object & populating the various attributes etc with its own attributes.

This is how Rails creates the illusion of *persistence* with this functionality -- it takes the ActiveRecord & populates the same data recursively

In order to get `fields_for` to work (which is the basis of `nested_attributes`, you need to *build* the associative ActiveRecord object in the action which renders the `form_for` (in your case `new`):

```
#app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb
Class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @expense = Expense.new
      @expense.items.build #-> required for fields_for to work
   end
end
```

Remember, the `nested_form` gem is not magic - it is essentially just a javascript plugin to replicate the `fields_for` elements rendered in your form already, and then append them to the DOM.

It essentially uses the `child_index: Time.now.to_i` "trick" to surmount the incremental `id` isue

--

**Attributes**

Secondly, you need to appreciate the error you're receiving

`expense_id` could be an attribute in the `items_attributes` objects. I've not seen this with pure Rails, but perhaps the `nested_form` gem appends a particular attribute to the objects or something

Either way, I believe the problem will be **how to associate your `items` objects** with your parent `Expense` object. To do this, I would do the following:

> 1. Check your params hash (see where `expense_id` is being passed)
> 2. Update your `strong_params` to allow the `expense_id`

**I KNOW THE PROBLEM**

> DATABASE - you likely don't have the `expense_id` column in the `items` table

---

**Fix**

You need to create a migration to put the `expense_id` [foreign_key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) into your `items` table

To do this, you should open your CMD and perform the following:

```
$ rails generate migration AddExpenseIDToItems
```

Then you can change the migration to have the following line:

```
add_column :expense_id, :items
```

Then you just need to do:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

This should resolve your issue

Comment: thanks a lot for the elaborate answer. I was following tutorial and missed out on the foreign key relation.

Comment: What could be wrong when the form submits the params (visible in the rails server) but does not create the records?

Answer (score 2):

Your controllers new action should be like this

```
def new
  @expense = Expense.new      
  @item = @expense.items.build
end
```

Also **if you are using rails 4 then you don't need nested_form_for gem**. Checkout [**`nested forms`**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). In your form you can simply use

```
<%= form_for @expense do |f| %>
  // expense fields
  <%= f.fields_for @item do |e| %>
    // item fields
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I added the line to new action. Now, the form itself isn't rendering and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @user3224820 in your item model do you have `belongs_to :expense`?

Comment: @user3224820 can you post your item model because i'm sure there is something wrong with how the associations are set up as first you were getting error in your create method when you were creating items and now in your new action where you are building items now

Comment: I have updated the question with the items model. I'm wondering about the same as well.

Comment: was this resolved? If so, how? I'm running into the same problem.